# Do I have a legitimate shortcut for finding the area under a curve?

Tags: area, curves

I'm studying functions, and recently I've spent some time looking into finding the area under a parabolic curve with integral calculus.

The methods I've found in this regard are very straightforward, though (and this must be because of a limited knowledge of more advanced methods) I find the solution can take quite some time to write up.

I've toyed around with what seems to be a very simple setup to get an accurate solution to the area under a curve, as well as the area between a curve and a right triangle...

[Sketch of the parabola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBkTn.jpg)

Parabola represents 1/4^2
    1 = 0 units
    1 = 0 units
    2 = 5 units
    2 = 1/4(5)^2 = 6.25 units

Regarding one-half of the figure above:

Area of the rectangle, R; from  = 0 to  = 5; to  = 6.25:
     =  ∗ 
     = 6.25 ∗ 5
     = 31.25 units

Area of the triangle; A:
     = 1/2 ∗   ∗ℎ
     = 1/2 ∗ 5 ∗ 6.25
     = 15.625 units

Area of under-curve; B:
     = 1 + 2
     = 1/6 ∗ 2(2 − 1) ∗ (2 − 1) + (1 ∗ 2)
     = 1/6 ∗ 2(5 − 0) ∗ (6.25 − 0) + (0 ∗ 5)
     = 1/6 ∗ (10) ∗ (6.25) + (0)
     = 10.41666667 units

Derived from Archimedes’ assertion that the area of the inside of a parabola is equal to 2/3ℎ. 2 describes the addition of the area of an inner rectangle that would result from a vertical phase shift; for example, a positive c-value in the form ^2++. In this case, 1 begins at a number >0, which creates a rectangle directly under the bottom edge of section B.

Area of the space between the triangle and curve; C:
     =  − ( + )
     = 31.25 − (15.625 + 10.41666667)
     = 5.20833333 units

2/3ℎ is 2/3 of the area of the triangle, and 1/3 of the area of the rectangle.

The area of C is proportionate to 5.20833333/15.625 = 1/3 of the area of A.

The area of C is proportionate to 5.20833333/10.41666667 = 1/2 of the area of B.

Equation for determining the area of C:
     = 1/6ℎ
     = 1/6(5)(6.25)
     = 5.208333333 units

I'm very sorry if the formatting doesn't work out for this post.  I'm not used to the layout, nor am I (as you can tell) a very effective communicator of math (haha).  Unless there's a '^' involved, any number following a variable is meant as subscript. I will re-post more carefully or email a .pdf to anybody who may have any problems wading through this.  Thank you for any advice and tips!

Comment: I don't know, but this seems like a lot longer process, and more error-prone, than the integral version!

Comment: Erm... and what exactly would be your question?

Comment: Question is simply whether or not this could be effective across various situations (do I have a legitimate shortcut for finding the area under a curve?)

Comment: It provides the exact same solution as an excel sheet geared to break the width into 5000 parts.  I personally do not know whether this is more effective as I admit there must be integral methods that are beyond my current skill level.

Comment: Is this a legitimate shortcut? Well it looks to me that you are just applying Archimedes' formula. Sure, his formula might be faster than integrating (this is debatable though - integrating polynomials is pretty fast), but it is limited in that you can only apply it to parabolas. I don't know what you mean by "more effective" - the effect of your method and the effect of integrating are both obtaining the area under the curve. They are equally effective at doing so.

Comment: Thank you, kccu.  Yes, I mention that I've relied on Archimedes in the text.  Apologies for the confusion, I used poor wording.  I do not wish to find a "more effective" version so much as I'm curious as to whether or not there are faster methods of finding the solution.  As of now, I assume that my skill with integrals is too minimal to achieve the ease of solving that some people experience.

Comment: With integration I can calculate the area between the triangle and the parabola in about 4 lines, which I would say is definitely faster than what you did. Your method is perfectly correct, though. Just keep learning and practicing integrals and you'll build up the skills.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time, kccu!